# I initialize char *str1 = nullptr and output to the screen... But when i want output to other variable i receive empty screen.. Why is it happening?

Tags: c++11, nullptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
const char *str = "Hello world";
char *str1 = nullptr;

std::cout << str << std::endl;  // when i output to screan i see hello world
std::cout << str1 << std::endl; // when i output to scream i sen nothing

str1 = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
strcpy(str1, str);
std::cout << str <<  std::endl; // when i output to scream again i sen nothing
std::cout << str1 << std::endl; // The same
}
```

Comment: I believe that your first output if `str1` when it's a null pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, please don't put your question in your title. The title should be a short summary of your problem, and the main question should be inside the question body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also suggest [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: i have project in github and i do not know why l get error. Can you check my code in github? if you have free time this reference on github https://github.com/bohdansyrovetnyk/constructor.githttps://github.com/bohdansyrovetnyk/constructor.git

Comment: char* must NEVER be nullptr when you call any string operation. They ALL assume the pointer is not nullptr from the beginnings of C.